# Windows 10 Home :can't reach ‘localhost:8000’ using Docker

Tags: windows, docker

I'm beginning to use Docker and following the tutorial (https://docs.docker.com/get-started/part2/) and I am stuck at this point:

```
docker run --publish 8000:8080 --detach --name bb bulletinboard:1.0
```

When I try to reach localhost:8080 it says "impossible to reach the site".

When I run `docker-machine ip` and visiting `http://192.168.99.100:8080` with a web client, it does not work.

Answer (score 1):

Please access with port 8000 like localhost:8000 because you mapping docker port from 8080 to 8000 to access from outsaide docker container

Comment: Thanks but no. even like this is not working.
EDIT: my problem was that i was using localhost instead of the IP and the wrong port. Thanks now it works!!

Comment: ok, I see. You need access to use your IP and port 8000 like this 192.168.99.100:8000

Answer (score 0):

Change Port from 8080 to 8000 like this http://192.168.99.100:8000 because you connect machine port 8000 to docker port 8080.

I hope it may help you.

Answer (score 0):

When you use `docker` commands, always remember..
`outside_world -> docker_world`

In your `8000:8080` means. You open your container to outside world on port `8000` , inside docker its `8080`

Or simply mapping docker port `8080` to `8000` outside.

In this configuration, you should use `localhost:8000`

`docker-machine ip` this is completely different network, thats why you can not access it. Its container network.